# Distinct only on one column

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN DISTINCT id(n) as nid, n.name
ORDER BY n.name
SKIP 5
LIMIT 10
```

I'd like to get distinct nids and their name properties but instead, the query filters the whole row, i.e applies distinct keyword on "nid, n.name" as whole. How can I achieve to get distinct nids and names of the nodes which have those distinct nids?

Comment: I don't think GROUP BY is a valid command in cypher queries.

Comment: I wasn't sure, it was only a thought=)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're looking for the `collect` function:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN id(n) as nid, collect(n.name)
SKIP 5
LIMIT 10
```